# Replace position of each div by 1 step clockwise after every 15 minutes with respect to world clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to chnage the position of each div by 1 step after every 15 minutes with respect to world clock like:

Div 1 > Div 2,
Div 2 > Div 3,
...
Div 9 > Div 1

[image: Exapmle Image]

```js
$(function () {
    var parent = $("#chnage-position");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

```css
#chnage-position > div {
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
}
#chnage-position {
    max-width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chnage-position">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

**Why World Clock?** I don't want the div position to reset if the page content is refreshed manually.

I have looked for many javaScript and jQuery codes here on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What help do you need?

Comment: i can shuffle the position randomly but i am unable to change the position one after one.

Comment: So your problem is that your code to move the relevant element is resulting in random shuffling, or that you don't know how to switch from random shuffling to a specific order? Regardless, please show the code - presumably JavaScript? - with which you attempted a solution. Also, [edit] your question to include pertinent details there, because comments are transitory and prone to deletion.

Comment: Updated the shuffle code in the question, i don't know how to get the desired result really looking forward for help. The main problem is to change the position of div after every 15 minutes and just by 1 step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is `prepend()` the last one each time.

Example in two second interval:

```js
var parent = $("#chnage-position");
setInterval(() => parent.prepend(parent.children().last()), 2000)
```

```css
#chnage-position>div {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#chnage-position {
  max-width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chnage-position">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i was looking for, Thankyou very much. Now i can increase the time interval but i also don't want the div position to reset if the page content is refreshed manually. how can i acheive that?

Comment: Interval is in ms... simple math to multiply by seconds and minutes. When page refreshes you want the last position maintained? Will need to store positions in localStorage. Give them an ID to do that

Comment: How can store positions in localStorage? Can you please help? i am open add the id's.

Comment: While Charlie has posted a perfectly functional jQuery answer, I thought I'd offer a native DOM approach to do the same thing in the event it might be useful: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2ug1b0my/1/).

Comment: Think of these like 9 advertisement boxes and each advertisement must stay at position 1 for 15 minutes, doesn't matter if the page is refreshed from the client-side or the div content is refreshed from the backend.

Comment: Example with sort on load https://jsfiddle.net/0ab1mfdg/

Comment: @charlietfl can you please check the code again in your file https://jsfiddle.net/0ab1mfdg/  I think it's not working, as the position of the divs is not changing.

Comment: Working fine for me. Did you run it several times? any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: In Incognito mode, it was not working. And which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Incognito probably blocking storage. Version is `edge` as noted just above the js block. edge = latest

Comment: Can we synchronize it with the world clock instead of storing locally? As it will always start from position 1 in every system, which can create a lot of confusion between clients. Different data will show to different clients.

Comment: Not sure what rules would be to honest? Nine elements vs 24 hours???

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help! I've accepted your answer as of now, but I'll need to create one more question with some more specifications. Like sometimes there could be less advertisements on a page, but yes each div must show at 1st position for 15 minutes in synchronization with world clock so that each client can see the same content.

Comment: Curious why it matters they see same order?

Comment: Each advertisement should get at least 15 minutes in the first position and 45 minutes in each raw. So that each client will be happy and no one have to pay extra to be on top.

Comment: What about just a random sort when page loads? Win win, no preferential treatment. Easy to display to customers also, they just need to do several refreshes to see it

Comment: but then how do we'll know which advertisement is shown on top and how many times in a day, all the packages/charges will depend on the time an advertisement is shown on the first position and raw.

Comment: Users typically don't spend long on a page. I've done ad systems that rotate on a much faster interval and were randomly sorted to start . There were multiple ads but only one block displayed at a time. Doubt they stayed visibly for more than 90 seconds ( I don't remember exactly) but if someone wanted to see them in one place all they would all be visible in a modal popup

Comment: The random sort gives all equal top spot ratio based on page loads